# Create a good drop&drag function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have 2 bordered space for tools and free-space (droppable-area). And this tool-space includes some shapes that can draggable, also droppable to free-space. But there is little bug...

When the figure drops to the free-space, some slide events happen. First of all, it happens after dropping any figure, then if we drag dropped figures, they affect each other with definite slides.

If you run below code on your computer and try this drop events you will understand my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```js
$(function() {
          $( ".draggable-item" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
          $(".droppable-area").droppable({
              drop: function(event, ui) {
                  $(this).append(ui.draggable);
              } 
          });
      } );
```

```css
.tool-space{
  border: 10px double #005580;
  min-height: 608px;
}
.free-space{
  border: 10px solid #005580;
  min-height: 608px;
}
.doitcenter{
  text-align: center;
}
.close-button{
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.shapes{
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.shapes:hover{
  cursor: move;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6e2154b1f7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="tool-space">
                    <div class="ui-widget-content doitcenter mt-2">
                     <span class="draggable-item">
                         <span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';" class="close-button">&times;</span>
                         <i class="far fa-square fa-2x shapes"></i>
                         
                     </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-widget-content doitcenter mt-2">
                      <span class="draggable-item">
                         <span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';" class="close-button">&times;</span>
                         <i class="far fa-circle fa-2x shapes"></i>
                         
                     </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-widget-content doitcenter mt-2">
                      <span class="draggable-item">
                         <span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';" class="close-button">&times;</span>
                         <i class="far fa-square fa-2x shapes"></i>
                         
                     </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-widget-content doitcenter mt-2">
                      <span class="draggable-item">
                         <span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';" class="close-button">&times;</span>
                         <i class="far fa-circle fa-2x shapes"></i>
                         
                     </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-10">
                <div class="free-space droppable-area">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar) to get an interface much like jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey , this is more usable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Largely the issue is that when the item is Dropped, Draggable has assigned `top` and `left` CSS values to the item. I suspect some other CSS is causing this to work based off some relative position inside the `free-space`.

You might consider using UI `.position()` to correct this.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".doitcenter").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    handle: ".shapes"
  });
  $(".droppable-area").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.appendTo(this).position({
        my: "center center-5",
        at: "center",
        of: event
      });
    }
  });
  $(".free-space").on("click", ".close-button", function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".doitcenter").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.tool-space {
  border: 10px double #005580;
  min-height: 608px;
}

.free-space {
  border: 10px solid #005580;
  min-height: 608px;
}

.free-space .doitcenter {
  width: 40px;
}

.doitcenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.close-button {
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shapes {
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.shapes:hover {
  cursor: move;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6e2154b1f7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="tool-space">
        <div class="ui-widget-content doitcenter mt-2">
          <span class="draggable-item"><span class="close-button">&times;</span><i class="far fa-square fa-2x shapes"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget-content doitcenter mt-2">
          <span class="draggable-item"><span class="close-button">&times;</span><i class="far fa-circle fa-2x shapes"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget-content doitcenter mt-2">
          <span class="draggable-item"><span class="close-button">&times;</span><i class="far fa-square fa-2x shapes"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget-content doitcenter mt-2">
          <span class="draggable-item"><span class="close-button">&times;</span><i class="far fa-circle fa-2x shapes"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="free-space droppable-area">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See More: https://jqueryui.com/position/